# Filter a pandas data frame by requiring presence of multiple items in a MultiIndex level

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a table of data with a multi-index. The first level of the multi-index is a name corresponding to a given sequence (DNA), the second level of the multi-index corresponds to a specific type of sequence variant `wt`, `m1`,`m2`, `m3` in the example below. Not all given `wt` sequences will have all types of variants(see `seqA`, and `seqC` below).

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':range(1,9), 'B':range(1,9), 'C': range(1,9)},
     index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('seqA', 'wt'), ('seqA', 'm1'),
     ('seqA', 'm2'),  ('seqB', 'wt'), ('seqB', 'm1'), ('seqB', 'm2'),
     ('seqB', 'm3'), ('seqC', 'wt') ]))

df.index.rename(['seq_name','type'], inplace=True)
print df

               A  B  C
seq_name type         
seqA     wt    1  1  1
         m1    2  2  2
         m2    3  3  3
seqB     wt    4  4  4
         m1    5  5  5
         m2    6  6  6
         m3    7  7  7
seqC     wt    8  8  8
```

I want to perform subsequent analyses on the data for only the sequences that have specific type(s) of variants (`m1` and `m2` in this example). So I want to filter my data frame to require that a given `seq_name` has **all** variant types that are specified in a `list`.

My current solution is pretty clunky, and not very aesthetically pleasing IMO.

```
var_l = ['wt', 'm1', 'm2']
df1 = df[df.index.get_level_values('type').isin(var_l)] #Filter varaints not of interest

set_l = []
for v in var_l: #Filter for each variant individually, and store seq_names
    df2 = df[df.index.get_level_values('type').isin([v])]
    set_l.append(set(df2.index.get_level_values('seq_name')))

seq_s = set.intersection(*set_l) # Get seq_names that only have all three variants
df3 = df1[df1.index.get_level_values('seq_name').isin(seq_s)] #Filter based on seq_name
print df3

               A  B  C
seq_name type         
seqA     wt    1  1  1
         m1    2  2  2
         m2    3  3  3
seqB     wt    4  4  4
         m1    5  5  5
         m2    6  6  6
```

I feel like there *must* be a one-liner that can do this. Something like:

```
var_l = ['wt', 'm1', 'm2']
filtered_df = filterDataframe(df1, var_l)
print filtered_df

               A  B  C
seq_name type         
seqA     wt    1  1  1
         m1    2  2  2
         m2    3  3  3
seqB     wt    4  4  4
         m1    5  5  5
         m2    6  6  6
```

I've tried searching this site, and have only found answers that let you filter by **any** item in a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with [`filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#filtration):

```
var_l = ['wt', 'm1', 'm2']

filtered_df=df.query('type in @var_l').groupby(level=0).filter(lambda x: len(x)==len(var_l))
print (filtered_df)
               A  B  C
seq_name type         
seqA     wt    1  1  1
         m1    2  2  2
         m2    3  3  3
seqB     wt    4  4  4
         m1    5  5  5
         m2    6  6  6
```

Another solution with [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) `size` and then filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
filtered_df = df.query('type in @var_l')
filtered_df = filtered_df[filtered_df.groupby(level=0)['A']
                                     .transform('size')
                                     .eq(len(var_l))
                                     .rename(None)]

print (filtered_df)
               A  B  C
seq_name type         
seqA     wt    1  1  1
         m1    2  2  2
         m2    3  3  3
seqB     wt    4  4  4
         m1    5  5  5
         m2    6  6  6
```

It works because:

```
print (filtered_df.groupby(level=0)['A'].transform('size'))
seq_name  type
seqA      wt      3
          m1      3
          m2      3
seqB      wt      3
          m1      3
          m2      3
seqC      wt      1
Name: A, dtype: int32

print (filtered_df.groupby(level=0)['A']
                  .transform('size')
                  .eq(len(var_l))
                  .rename(None))
seq_name  type
seqA      wt       True
          m1       True
          m2       True
seqB      wt       True
          m1       True
          m2       True
seqC      wt      False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thanks! The first solution does exactly what I want. I'm relatively new to pandas, and wasn't familiar with `query` or `groupby` functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

***option 1***
using `query` + `stack`
As @jezrael pointed out, this depends on no `NaN` existing in rows to be analyzed.

```
df.query('type in @var_l').unstack().dropna().stack()

                 A    B    C
seq_name type               
seqA     m1    2.0  2.0  2.0
         m2    3.0  3.0  3.0
         wt    1.0  1.0  1.0
seqB     m1    5.0  5.0  5.0
         m2    6.0  6.0  6.0
         wt    4.0  4.0  4.0
```

Preserve the `dtypes`

```
df.query('type in @var_l').unstack().dropna().stack().astype(df.dtypes)

               A  B  C
seq_name type         
seqA     m1    2  2  2
         m2    3  3  3
         wt    1  1  1
seqB     m1    5  5  5
         m2    6  6  6
         wt    4  4  4
```

---

***option 2***
using `filter`
it checks if the sub-index intersected with the `var_l` is the same as `var_l`

```
def correct_vars(df, v):
    x = set(v)
    n = df.name
    y = set(df.xs(n).index.intersection(v))
    return x == y

df.groupby(level=0).filter(correct_vars, v=var_l)

               A  B  C
seq_name type         
seqA     wt    1  1  1
         m1    2  2  2
         m2    3  3  3
seqB     wt    4  4  4
         m1    5  5  5
         m2    6  6  6
         m3    7  7  7
```

Comment: I think problem of your solution is if some `NaN` row, then it remove `seq` :(

Comment: @jezrael `True` I'll try to fix